# pythonic way to detect specific pandas column type

Tags: pandas

what is the most pythonic  way to select columns based on there dtype? (only needing the columns and not the entire df as with [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html?highlight=select_dtypes) ) .
assuming we are looking for `datetime` columns,  currently we are using  :

```
date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if "datetime" in str(df[col].dtype]
```

another option is

```
date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if isinstance(df[col].dtype, pd.core.dtypes.dtypes.XXXX)]
```

but could not find the correct dtype   for `dtype('<M8[ns]')`.
`np.datetime64` does not detect it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype.html), for list of all possible functions check [`general_utility_functions`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/general_utility_functions.html#dtype-introspection):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  
print (df)

date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if pd.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype(df[col])]
print (date_cols)
['Date']
```

Simplier is [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with columns:

```
date_cols = df.select_dtypes('datetime64').columns
print (date_cols)
Index(['Date'], dtype='object')
```

Or:

```
date_cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.map(pd.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype)]
print (date_cols)
Index(['Date'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_dtype

ts = df.dtypes.apply(is_datetime64_dtype)
ts[ts].index
```